# Repeat TextSwitcher Text after 10 minute

Tags: java, android

I have a `array` for `TextSwitcher`  : `private String [] word = {"A","B",......};`
I have put a button below the `TextSwitcher` like if anyone click the button the text will be show after 10 min . If the user open the app tomorrow the text will show at first. Can anyone help me to achieve this? I don't know how to change the position and there will be more than 2000 words.

Comment: add what you have tried

Comment: I don't know how to archive it how can i add ?

Comment: You can try using [Handler().postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) or [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) . If you want more help, you should post some code, or go deeper with what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community. I have added the simplest way of doing the above functionality.

```
var words = listOf<String>("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K","L")
var counter = 0
var Timer =  1000L
```

and in on Create

```
 var textView =  findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvCounter)
    Handler().postDelayed( Runnable {
    if(counter>= words.size){
      counter = 0
        }
        textView.text = words.get(counter)
        counter++
    },Timer)
```

do clear this handler, otherwise, it will introduce activity leaks

Comment: How it will? If i use your method it will shows every single words after 10 min . But i don't want to do that . if user select the button it will only repeat that specific word after 10 min. Can you help me to achieve it?